# Invalid parameter 1: Parameter index is out of range. Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, hashmap

I have a Spring Boot application that grabs an XML from an MQ and maps the XML in a hash map and runs an update query based on what is in the XML. I'm having an issue when it comes to using the Hash Map. I can run the query (by hard coding the values) and it will update the table accordingly, but when I try to use the Hash Map to pass to the query (with the same values) I get this error that says "Invalid parameter 1: Parameter index is out of range." I can't figure out why the hash map isn't working, because it appears to map correctly when I just output it to the screen. Any help is appreciated! (Sorry about the formatting. Couldn't figure out how to separate the xml and the code into two pages.)

```
   @Repository
public class OrderChargeRepository extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    @Autowired
    private Properties queries;

    @Autowired
    public OrderChargeRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
        super();

        this.setDataSource(dataSource);
        }

    public void update(SupplierPayments supplierPayments) {
        String sqlUpdate = queries.getProperty("updateTable");
        for (SupplierPayment supplierPayment : supplierPayments.getSupplierPayments()) {
            for (Invoices invoices : supplierPayment.getSupplierPayment()) {
                for (Invoice invoice : invoices.getInvoices()) {
                    for (InvoiceLines invoiceLines : invoice.getInvoice()) {
                        for (InvoiceLine invoiceLine : invoiceLines.getInvoiceLines()) {
                            Map<String,Object> parms = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                            parms.put("paymentId", supplierPayment.getID());
                            parms.put("paymentDate", supplierPayment.getPaymentDate());
                            parms.put("invoiceLineAmount", invoiceLine.getAmount());
                            parms.put("referenceNumber", invoice.getreferenceNumber());
                            parms.put("scac", supplierPayment.getSCAC());
                            parms.put("supplierInvoiceReferenceNumber", invoice.getSupplierInvoiceReferenceNumber());
                            this.getJdbcTemplate().update(sqlUpdate, parms);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//properties.xml
//Contains query property
<util:properties id="queries">
    <prop key="updateTable">
        <![CDATA[
        UPDATE ALI.TORDER_CHARGE
            SET  CHK_NBR = :paymentId
            , PAY_D = DATE(:paymentDate)
            , PAY_A = :invoiceLineAmount
            , LST_UPD_S = CURRENT TIMESTAMP
            , LST_UPD_UID = 'BATCH'
            WHERE ORD_I =  (Select ORD_I from aaa.torder where ORD_NBR_CH = :referenceNumber)
                AND CUS_C =  :scac
                AND IVC_REF_NBR = :supplierInvoiceReferenceNumber 
                ]]> 
                    </prop>
                </util:properties>

     </beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getJdbcTemplate()` in JdbcDaoSupport returns a JdbcTemplate. So the method you're calling is `JdbcTemplate.update(String sql, Object... args)`, and thus

- the query isn't expected to contain named arguments, but only placeholders (`?`)
- the whole map is used as the unique, first argument of the query

You need a [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) to do what you want to achieve. Just wrap the "classic" JdbcTemplate into a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, and it should work fine.